# Get an Openload VTT subtitle link

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, vtt

I'd like to use Greasemonkey to add a subtitle download button for Openload VTT subtitles. However, I can't figure out how to access the **<track>** tag.

Take, for example, this [French video clip](https://openload.co/embed/rjC09fkPLYs) with English subtitles.
When I looked at the source code in Firefox, I found this:

```
<video id="olvideo" width="100%" height="100%" crossorigin="anonymous" controls>
    <track kind="captions" src="https://thumb.oloadcdn.net/subtitle/rjC09fkPLYs/vt8zTaIaVqQ.vtt" srclang="en" label="English" default />
</video>
```

Why doesn't my proof-of-concept Greasemonkey code work?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Openload
// @include     *openload.co*
// @run-at      document-idle
// ==/UserScript==

var video = document.querySelector("video");

if (video) {
    var track = video.querySelector("track");
    if (track) {
        alert ("<track> FOUND.");
    } else {
        alert ("<track> NOT found!");
    }

} else { 
    alert ("<video> tag not found");
}
```

(When I ran the script I got the message "<track> NOT found!".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple/basic script.
I didn't know which version of GM you are using. This is written for GM4
If you are using GM 3, then change:

```
GM.xmlHttpRequest -> GM_xmlhttpRequest
GM.openInTab -> GM_openInTab
```

It opens the subtitles in a new tab so you can save it.
You can run it on both embed and normal file pages.
e.g.
https://openload.co/embed/rjC09fkPLYs
https://openload.co/f/rjC09fkPLYs

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Openload Subtitle Download
// @namespace     erosman
// @description   Openload Subtitle Download
// @include       https://openload.co/f/*
// @include       https://openload.co/embed/*
// @grant         GM.xmlHttpRequest
// @grant         GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @grant         GM.openInTab
// @grant         GM_openInTab
// @author        erosman
// @version       1.0
// ==/UserScript==

/* --------- Note ---------
  This script download Openload Subtitles.
  It runs on both embed and normal file pages.
  --------- History ---------


  1.0   Initial release

*/

(() => { // anonymous function wrapper, for error checking & limiting scope, async FF52+
'use strict';

if (frameElement || !location || !document.body) { return; } // end execution if in a frame/object/embedding points


// --- get the document
GM.xmlHttpRequest({
  method: 'GET',
  url: location.href,
  onload: result => processResult(result.responseText),
  onerror: error => console.log(error)
});

function processResult(str) {

  // convert to DOM
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');

  // get tracks with source, convert to array for forEach, 
  // open each subtitle (if there are more than one) in a new tab
  // you can save it from there
  [...doc.querySelectorAll('track[src]')].forEach(item => GM.openInTab(item.src));
}

// end of anonymous function
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the great script! (It works fine with Firefox & Greasemonkey and Chrome & Tampermonkey.)

Answer (score 4):

The [link you gave](https://openload.co/embed/rjC09fkPLYs) **doesn't ever have a `<track>` node**, at least for me (un logged-in, and not the video's creator).

Nevertheless, this is may be a standard AJAX problem. That is, if the node is added via javascript (AJAX), the Tampermonkey script will have finished before the target node is loaded.

Use standard ajax-aware techniques for that.  One way:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Openload.co, Report on track nodes
// @match    *://openload.co/embed/*
// @match    *://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/pages/tabbed/track.html
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.

waitForKeyElements ("track", reportTrackNode);

//-- For Mozilla page, which uses shadow DOM:
waitForKeyElements ("shadow-output", reportTrackNodeWithinShadowDOM);

function reportTrackNode (jNode) {
    console.log ("Found <track>:", jNode[0]);
}

function reportTrackNodeWithinShadowDOM (jNode) {
    var sr      = jNode[0].shadowRoot;
    var trck    = $(sr.childNodes).find ("track");
    if (trck.length === 0)  return true;  //  Keep waiting.

    console.log ("Found <track>:", trck[0]);
}
```

Note that the above code works in Tampermonkey, Violentmonkey, and earlier versions of Greasemonkey.  It *should* work in Greasemonkey 4+, but that engine is very broken, so no guarantees.

You can see that the code does find the track when it exists (even in a shadow DOM) by installing the script and visiting [this MDN video demo page](https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/pages/tabbed/track.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, your code didn't work with Greasemonkey/TamperMonkey. 

`The link you gave doesn't ever have a <track> node[...]` I forgot to mention that I installed an ad blocker. (Without it, you'll see a couple of nasty ads, which, of course, don't have <track> nodes.) 
Please visit the site (with an ad blocker) and wait until the video clip plays. You'll notice that it indeed plays English VTT subtitles.

Comment: @NemoXXX, I always use adblockers and scriptblockers.  Even had to temporarily reduce a couple settings to see the video at all.  I see the subtitles but there is no `<track>` node.  Try visiting the link in a new browser (or instance) where you are not logged in and have no cookies set. .. And you can see that the above script works by changing `track` to `video`.  Or, install the updated script and visit the MDN link given.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code! It works fine with the MDN link, but not with the openload video. 
`I see the subtitles but there is no <track> node.` Since the subtitles aren't hard-coded, how are they played if there's no `<track>` node?
`And you can see that the above script works by changing track to video.` It does return a video element (`video id="olvideo_html5_api`). However, when I select View Page Source in Firefox, I see a different video tag (`video id="olvideo"`), which does have <track> nodes. Most likely openload.co runs a script that adds `<track>` nodes on the fly.

Comment: If the track nodes are added on the fly AND it's not a flash player AND it's not in a shadow DOM (those need special handling as shown), then the script would catch it anyway.  I have never seen a track node on that page in neither Firefox nor Chrome.  If you can come up with a reliable recipe for an unregistered, brand new user to see one, then we can figure it out.  Also, that site has a few malware reports.  As for how those subtitles appear, is there a shadow dom or iframe somewhere?  (I didn't see one, but didn't look hard either.)

Comment: Since the bounty will expire soon, I have one more question for you: why does the code that I see when I select View Page Source doesn't match the code that GreaseMonkey/TamperMonkey sees? (When I select View Page Source I see that tags that I need.)

Comment: @NemoXXX, that's probably because of ajax timing or because of something like shadow DOM.  I don't see the claimed tag in either FF or Chrome. On either windows or Linux.  Come up with a recipe for me to see it and I can help you further.  What browser version? What OS? What happens if you switch to a different browser **where you have never logged in**?

Comment: I see the vtt track only with the 64bit Linux/Windows 10 versions of Firefox 63.0.1 (View Page Source) and Opera 56.0.3051.70 (Developer > Page Source). 

I don't see it with MS Edge and Google Chrome.

Comment: @NemoXXX, I see and also erosman beat me to it.  That site/page loads `<track>`s *statically*, and then uses javascript to erase them from the DOM. Very hokey.  Anyway, you have your workaround, fetch the page a second time, via XHR request, and custom process the source.